# Open a file and replace strings in C#

Tags: c#, string, file

I'm trying to figure out the best way to open an existing file and replace all strings that match a declared string with a new string, save it then close.

Suggestions ?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Can be done in one line:

```
File.WriteAllText("Path", Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText("Path"), "[Pattern]", "Replacement"));
```

Comment: This will load the entire file into memory

Answer (score 30):

If you're **reading large files** in, and your string for replacement may not appear broken across multiple lines, I'd suggest something like the following...

```
private static void ReplaceTextInFile(string originalFile, string outputFile, string searchTerm, string replaceTerm)
{
    string tempLineValue;
    using (FileStream inputStream = File.OpenRead(originalFile) )
    {
        using (StreamReader inputReader = new StreamReader(inputStream))
        {
            using (StreamWriter outputWriter = File.AppendText(outputFile))
            {
                while(null != (tempLineValue = inputReader.ReadLine()))
                {
                    outputWriter.WriteLine(tempLineValue.Replace(searchTerm,replaceTerm));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you'd have to remove the original file, and rename the new one to the original name, but that's trivial - as is adding some basic error checking into the method.

Of course, if your replacement text could be across two or more lines, you'd have to do a little more work, but I'll leave that to you to figure out. :)

Comment: I would ditch the nested usings in favor of stacking them, but I think that is really just a preference. More than one nesting makes me cringe a little;)

Comment: I would like to know how this code could be modified to support Binary files.

Comment: what's about huge files ? https://web.archive.org/web/20140316075223/http://towardsnext.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/replace-data-in-file-c/

Answer (score 12):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static void ReplaceInFile(
                      string filePath, string searchText, string replaceText )
{

    var content = string.Empty;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( filePath ))
    {
        content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
    }

    content = Regex.Replace( content, searchText, replaceText );

    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter( filePath ))
    {
        writer.Write( content );
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, you might want to add `usings` around the streamreader/writer, which is best practice afaik.

Comment: You could replace the StreamReader with File.ReadAllText and StreamWriter with File.WriteAllText. A little less code... Also, depending on what you are replacing, you might need to Regex.Escape searchText, or use string.Replace.

Comment: Without reading it into memory you would process the file line by line.  You could write it out to a new file and copy it to the old file name if you wanted to replace the file.

Comment: What's about for several replaces in the same file?

Comment: What's about huge files? http://towardsnext.wordpress.com/2009/02/02/replace-data-in-file-c/

Answer (score 12):

Slight improvement on the accepted answer that doesn't require Regex, and which meets the requirements of the question:

```
File.WriteAllText("Path", File.ReadAllText("Path").Replace("SearchString", "Replacement"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class ReadAndChange : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    ArrayList FolderList = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList FolderListSearch = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList FileList = new ArrayList();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AllFolderList("D:\\BinodBackup\\Nilesh\\14.5.2013\\Source");
        foreach (string Path in FolderList)
        {
            AllFileList(Path);
        }
        foreach (string Path in FileList)
        {
            ReplaceFile(Path, Path.Replace("Source", "EditedCode"));
        }

        //string SourcePath = "D:\\BinodBackup\\Nilesh\\14.5.2013\\Onesource\\Onesource\\UserManagement\\UserControls\\AddUserDetails.ascx.cs";
        //string ReplacePath = "D:\\AddUserDetails.ascx.cs";
        //ReplaceFile(SourcePath, ReplacePath);
    }

    private static void ReplaceFile(string SourcePath, string ReplacePath)
    {
        int counter = 1;
        string line;

        // Read the file and display it line by line.
        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(SourcePath);
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (!(line.Contains("//")))
            {
                if (line.Contains(".LogException("))
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine(counter.ToString() + ": " + line);
                    string[] arr = line.Split(',');
                    string stringToReplace = arr[0].Replace("LogException", "Publish") + " , " + arr[2].Trim() + " , " + arr[3].Replace(");", "").Trim() + " , " + arr[1].Trim() + ");";
                    //File.WriteAllText(currentPath, Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText(currentPath), line, line + " Added"));
                    File.WriteAllText(ReplacePath, File.ReadAllText(ReplacePath).Replace(line, stringToReplace));
                    //ReplaceInFile(currentPath, line, stringToReplace);
                }
            }

            counter++;
        }

        file.Close();
    }
    private void AllFileList(string FolderPath)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(FolderPath);
        DirectoryInfo[] subdir = dir.GetDirectories();
        if (subdir.Length > 0)
        {

            foreach (DirectoryInfo dr in subdir)
            {
                FileInfo[] files1 = dr.GetFiles();
                foreach (FileInfo file in files1)
                {
                    if(file.Name.EndsWith(".cs"))
                    CheckAndAdd((file.DirectoryName + "\\" + file.Name), FileList);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    private void AllFolderList(string FolderPath)
    {
        string CurFolderPatgh = FolderPath;
        Again:
        AddToArrayList(CurFolderPatgh);
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(CurFolderPatgh);
        DirectoryInfo[] subdir = dir.GetDirectories();

        if (subdir.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (DirectoryInfo dr in subdir)
            {
                AddToArrayList(((System.IO.FileSystemInfo)(dir)).FullName + "\\" + dr.Name);
            }
        }
        if (FolderListSearch.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string dr in FolderListSearch)
            {
                CurFolderPatgh = dr;
                FolderListSearch.Remove(dr);
                goto Again;
            }
        }
    }

    private void AddToArrayList(string FolderPath)
    {
        if (!(FolderList.Contains(FolderPath)))
        {
            CheckAndAdd(FolderPath, FolderList);
            CheckAndAdd(FolderPath, FolderListSearch);
        }
    }

    private void CheckAndAdd(string FolderPath,ArrayList ar)
    {
        if (!(ar.Contains(FolderPath)))
        {
            ar.Add(FolderPath);
        }
    }

    public static void ReplaceInFile(
                      string filePath, string searchText, string replaceText)
    {

        var content = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
        }

        content = content.Replace(searchText, replaceText);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
        {
            writer.Write(content);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace DevExpressFileEditing
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<FileInfo> _files;
        private static Dictionary<string, string> _replaceList;

        static void Main()
        {
            _files = new List<FileInfo>();
            _replaceList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            Console.WriteLine("Dark directory searching");
            SearchFilesInDirectories(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Sourcebank\Dark"));

            Console.WriteLine("Light directory searching");
            SearchFilesInDirectories(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Sourcebank\Light"));

            Console.WriteLine("{0} files found", _files.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

            Console.WriteLine("Replace dictinary creating");
            CreateReplaceList();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} item added", _replaceList.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

            Console.Write("Replacement doing");
            for (int i = 0; i < _files.Count; i++)
            {
                var fileInfo = _files[i];
                Console.CursorLeft = 0;
                Console.Write("{0} of {1}", i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), _files.Count.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                ReplaceInFile(fileInfo.FullName);
            }
            Console.CursorLeft = 0;
            Console.Write("Replacement done");
        }

        private static void SearchFilesInDirectories(DirectoryInfo dir)
        {
            if (!dir.Exists) return;

            foreach (DirectoryInfo subDirInfo in dir.GetDirectories())
                SearchFilesInDirectories(subDirInfo);

            foreach (var fileInfo in dir.GetFiles())
                _files.Add(fileInfo);
        }

        private static void CreateReplaceList()
        {
            _replaceList.Add("Color=\"#FFF78A09\"", "Color=\"{DynamicResource AccentColor}\"");
            _replaceList.Add("Color=\"{StaticResource ColorHot}\"", "Color=\"{DynamicResource AccentColor}\"");
            _replaceList.Add("Color=\"#FFCC0000\"", "Color=\"{DynamicResource AccentColor}\"");
            _replaceList.Add("To=\"#FFCC0000\"", "To=\"{DynamicResource AccentColor}\"");
            _replaceList.Add("To=\"#FFF78A09\"", "To=\"{DynamicResource AccentColor}\"");
            _replaceList.Add("Background=\"#FFF78A09\"", "Background=\"{DynamicResource Accent}\"");
            _replaceList.Add("Foreground=\"#FFF78A09\"", "Foreground=\"{DynamicResource Accent}\"");
            _replaceList.Add("BorderBrush=\"#FFF78A09\"", "BorderBrush=\"{DynamicResource Accent}\"");
            _replaceList.Add("Value=\"#FFF78A09\"", "Value=\"{DynamicResource Accent}\"");
            _replaceList.Add("Fill=\"#FFF78A09\"", "Fill=\"{DynamicResource Accent}\"");
        }

        public static void ReplaceInFile(string filePath)
        {
            string content;
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }

            content = _replaceList.Aggregate(content, (current, item) => current.Replace(item.Key, item.Value));

            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
            {
                writer.Write(content);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For showing how to use Aggregate() to replace the text while still using good practices, +1.

Comment: warning:  _replaceList.Aggregate  did NOT  replace all my occurrences correctly when I was replacing strings that contained parentheses (strange unexpected behavior in that Aggregate). I had to go back to string.Replace() in a for loop for this to work. but the for loop used up 300Mb of unreleased workng memory.  So yeah, lucky my use case was a small one off!