# Edit postgresql.conf file from c#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I'm creating a Windows Service application in c# to automate PostGreSql database backups. (With scheduled tasks to do full backups, clean old files, ...)

To do it, I first need to edit the postgresql.conf file, uncomment some parameters and change some values to enable Write-Ahead Logging ( WAL ).

I would like to do it automatically from my code. Is there a simple way or existing code to do it ?

I found [this Linux script](http://blog.endpoint.com/2011/08/changing-postgresqlconf-from-script.html) but I need to do it from C#...

Example of parameters to edit:

```
# - Archiving -                                       

archive_mode = on                          

archive_command = 'copy "%p" "C:\\Backups\\%f"'                            

archive_timeout = 600 # force a logfile segment switch after this number of seconds
```

Is there a standard name for this kind of configuration file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to open the file, do a "find & replace" then save the changes.

This is how you would do that.
[How to Find And Replace Text In A File With C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509532/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-in-c-sharp)