# Replacing a word in a txt using c# in visual studios

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

Does anyone no a way to replace a word in a txt file with another preset one? maybe using openfile or savefile to find the txt first and then use a text box to determin said word and replace it.

Example using open file to find the txt then typing a word e.g. dog to replace by using a the text box, and all words that have dog in the txt file get changed to cat.
Im using visual studios 2012.

if its possible help is much appreciated

Comment: Well, you could do this with notepad and use its "find and replace" functionality.

Comment: ^ So, yes, it is possible. Start coding.

Comment: Please refrain from posting questions without any research. A quick google search would provide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509532/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-with-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Find And Replace Text In A File With C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509532/how-to-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-with-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the complete version

```
private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)

System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);

private void button2_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)

String find textbox1.Text
string replace = "dog";

File.writeAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName,File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName).Replace(find, replace));
```

also need to add a textbox

Answer (score 0):

You could just use

```
string find = "word";
string replace = "replaced";
File.WriteAllText("C:\\yourfile.txt", File.ReadAllText("C:\\yourfile.txt").Replace(find, replace));
```

Comment: You're welcome could you upvote my answer @swordboot