# Find and Delete Characters in String

Tags: c#, findandmodify

My program reads registry key values and combines those values with the installation path. I also read the installation path from the registry.

i.e. `String dllInstpath = installPath + rKey` which equals to: 
  `C:\Program Files (x86)\NSi\AutoStore Workflow 6\HpOXPdCaptureRes.dll`

I then use `FileVersionInfo` on the string above to get the file information of `HpOXPdCaptureRes.dll` from it's install path and write all the values to a notepad.

My problem is the TRUE dll name does not have 'Res' in the file name. The registry only has the file name with 'Res' in the file name. What I need to do is read from a text file and find all 'Res' and remove them from the line of text within the notepad file.

So the output should look like this:

Current:
  `HpOXPdCaptureRes.dll`

New:
  `HpOXPdCapture.dll`

I have read online and I see the best way to do this is to use `ReadAllLines` and `WriteAllLines`. However I am not sure how to implement the find and replace. I have seen a lot of examples on how to remove spaces, invalid characters, etc., but I haven't been able to find an example for what I need.

Summary:

- Read text file
- Fine `Res` in all lines of text and remove
- Retain current text file, i.e. remove `Res` and close file

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915632/open-a-file-and-replace-strings-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `File.ReadAllLines` and `File.WriteAllLines`.

Example:

Read all the lines and replace the value you want on each line, then write the lines again

```
File.WriteAllLines("textFilePath",File.ReadAllLines("textFilePath").Select(line => line.Replace("Res.dll", ".dll")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just open the file and read all lines using 'File.ReadAllLines'. Then use `Replace` to remove the `Res`:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("yourFileName");
var output = lines.Select(x => x.Replace("Res.dll", ".dll")).ToArray();
```

To later save them back you can use `File.WriteAllLines`:

```
File.WriteAllLines("yourFileName", output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read everything from file, replace all occurrences of 'res' and write to file:

```
        String filename = "fileName";

        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
        String content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();

        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename);
        sw.Write(content.Replace("res", ""));
        sw.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string you are replacing is guaranteed to be unique in the string - "res.dll" at the end of the string for instance - then you can use `Replace` method of the `String` class to do the replacement:

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(sourceFile);
lines = lines.select(l => l.Replace("res.dll", ".dll").ToList();
```

Or if case sensitivity is an issue:

```
lines = lines.Select(l => l.Substring(l.Length - 7).ToLower() == "res.dll" ? l.Substring(0, l.Length - 7) + ".dll" : l).ToList();
```

For more complex cases you might need to use a regular expression to identify the section of the string to replace.  Or you might want to split the string int path and filename, modify the filename and join it back together.