# how to replace multiple occurrences of a substring in C#

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am just starting to learn C# and I am trying to replace all occurrences  of a certain substring in a text file with a \  if the text is not separated  by whitespace or not . What is the easiest way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show an example of what the input and output could and should be, please? It's a little hard to understand what you mean from your question.

Comment: take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915632/open-a-file-and-replace-strings-in-c-sharp

Comment: I learned programming using python and just started C# this week so to be honest I have not even gotten close to a correct solution.

Comment: @minitech I am trying to parse a txt file and change every occurrence of the sub string "BACKS" to an actual "\".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. read in your file:

   ```
   var fileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\YourFile.txt");
   ```
2. replace text:

   ```
   fileContents = fileContents.Replace("BACKS", "\\");
   ```
3. write the file to filesystem:

   ```
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\YourFile.txt", fileContents);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna use Regex

Simple and single statement

```
File.WriteAllText("c:\\test.txt", Regex.Replace(File.ReadAllText("c:\\test.txt"), @"\bBACKS\b", "\\"));
```

Comment: Thanks Civa that worked well too. why do I need to use double \\ on path  when using regex as opposed to single \ when using MUG4N'S method?

Comment: it's because of the @ sign in my code. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556133/whats-the-in-front-of-a-string-in-c