# Data Flow SSIS - Common destination table, different structure flat files

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I have multiple flat files(.csv) as my source in a folder.Each file has varying number of columns which may or may not intersect with other files. However, all columns in any source file are always present in my destination table that contains the super set of all these columns.

My requirement is to loop through each of these files and dynamically map columns that are available in that file to the destination table(header names of csv file match column names in table).

```
Structure of File 1:
id, name, age, email

Structure of File 2:
id, name, age, address, country

Structure of File 3:
id, name, age, address

Structure of Destination Table:
id, name, age, address, country, email
```

I want to populate the table for all columns with data for what is available and `NULL` for what's not for every record. How can I achieve this using SSIS?

Comment: Most painless method is to insert all of the records from the three files into temp/staging tables and execute a stored procedure to populate the table with your logic inside.  You can do all your merging logic in SSIS itself, but that's much more of a hassle...

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by adding one `Flat File Connection Manager` add only one column with Data type `DT_WSTR` and a length of `4000` *(assuming it's name is `Column0`)*

- In the `dataflow task` add a `Script Component` after the `Flat File Source`
- In mark `Column0` as Input Column and Add 6 Output Columns *`(id, name, age, address, country, email)`*
- In the `Input0_ProcessInputRow` method split this column and assign values to output column. *(you can write the logic you want)* you can read answers at the following question to get an example: [Reading CSV file some missing columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41108845/reading-csv-file-some-missing-columns/41202934#41202934)

Answer (score -1):

The `Flat File Source` does not support dynamic file format, you have to use multiple sources to load these files.

Comment: This is wrong, you can do ignore columns in `Flat File Connection manager` (read line as one column) and split them using derrived columns or scripts