# SQL Server Import Wizard Importing Comma Delimited File with Commas In Field

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I have a text file I'm trying to import that contains 14 million records, but it's delimited with commas and there is one field that also contains commas, and there is no text qualifer to denote that the field has multiple values separated by commas.  Does anyone know a way import with this scenario, or to correct delimited file for import?

I'm using SQL Server 2012.  I'm open to correcting the text file via C#, VB.NET, or if there is a way in SSIS to correct it.

Comment: Does that field always contain the same number of commas or is it variable?

Comment: It's variable, that field may contain no commas, sometimes 2 values with commas or 3 values with commas

Comment: Can you regenerate the CSV file WITH text qualifiers?

Comment: The text file is already generated, and I have no way to re-generate it. Unless I use C# or VB to programically place the field with double quotes around it.  My scripting skills are very limitted though.  Do you have a similar script that could do this?

Comment: The only way I can think of to handle that would be to split the line on the commas, take the appropriate number of values from the beginning and the end and then assume what's left in the middle is that one field.  If there were multiple fields like that then it would be impossible.

Comment: The values for the field in question can only be the following:

NULL 
AGT
AGT, CLT
AGT, CLT, CTL, ISS
AGT, CLT, ISS
AGT, CLT, ISS, CTL
AGT, CLT, ISS, EXCH
AGT, CTL
AGT, CTL, CLT, ISS
AGT, ISS, CLT
BROKDEAL
BROKDEAL, CLT
Client Role
Dual Role
Non Client Role

Comment: All possible values of the column before Role is:

Active
Deactivated
Merged
Prospective

All possible values of the column after Role is: 

NULL
1.1. Active Rem
1.1. Rem - Active Rem
1.3.4. Become Inactive

Comment: You can use vb.net to insert those records.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import CSV File Error : Column Value containing column delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412216/import-csv-file-error-column-value-containing-column-delimiter)