# SSIS error: delimiter for column "columnX" is not found

Tags: sql, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012

This question was asked here before but the solutions proposed don't seem to be working for me.

I'm trying to import a text file pipe delimited text qualifier `"`. The SSIS package is returning the error message

> delimiter for column "columnX" is not found

where column X is the last field in the file.

In the connection manager advanced tab, I have set up the column delimiter for `columnX` to `{LF}` while all the other fields are set to vertical `|`.

I have verified the file and there are no missing fields. There are some null values but all the fields are there.

I can't point out what is causing this. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post minimum code and text file which is required to reproduce the problem? See the help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @marcia12 it is good to read the [Tour page](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 8):

I realize that this thread is old, but I was looking for a solution to this exact problem and did not find it.  Deleting the flat file connection manager is extreme when I had so many columns that I adjusted the DataTypes for.

In my scenario with this error, it was the last column and the delimiter had switched from {CR}{LF} to {LF}.  I switched it back to {CR}{LF} and it worked.

Also, under general, the Header row delimiter had also changed to {LF} and I changed it to {CR}{LF} too.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to delete the flat file connection manager, and recreate it so it will automatically set all options. Just select the column delimiter to `|`

If it doesn't works you have to verify that flat file does not contains bad rows.

Check these solutions they may helps:

- [SSIS ragged file not recognized CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44245738/ssis-ragged-file-not-recognized-crlf/44251046#44251046)
- [SSIS reading LF as terminator when its set as CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44164504/ssis-reading-lf-as-terminator-when-its-set-as-crlf/44218237#44218237)
- [Import CSV File Error : Column Value containing column delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412216/import-csv-file-error-column-value-containing-column-delimiter)

Or if you have installed sql server try importibg this fla file to an sql server table using *import and export wizard* and check the data after importing it may helps detecting the lines containning errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try to increase ColumnWidth in the Advanced tab on the Flat file Connection Manager Editor.

[Pic with example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckhLR.png)

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me on several occasions.  Each time it has been caused by someone adding a column to the csv file. The error happens when it gets to the end of the last column and expects a carriage return line feed cr/lf, but finds only the carriage return because there is an added column.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this on some CSVs I had exported from Oracle SQL Developer and needed to import into SQL Server.

After *many* failed attempts to import my problematic CSV, I discovered a quirk - For some un-god-known reason, the header row terminated with CRLF while the data rows terminated with LF. Doing a mass replace of carriage returns in Notepad++ before importing allowed me to proceed. SSIS seems to have difficulty importing flat files with mixed line endings.

One other callout in case it helps some other poor soul - if you're importing a max length varchar column, you may need to change the data type to **Text Stream** in order for SSIS/Import Wizard to process it.

Comment: This ought to be the accepted answer - this worked for me. I wish I could upvote this twice.

Answer (score 0):

Do not set the last column delimiter to LF. If the file row ends with {LF} (which I believe you have verified) then set the **header row delimiter** to {LF}:
[image]

Comment: the last column delimiter is always equal to the row delimiter. changing it can causes errors

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be more related to badly formatted delimiters in csv files.
Hope the following threads will help:

[How to replace double quotes in derived column transformation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210744/how-to-replace-double-quotes-in-derived-column-transformation)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fe6be73a-d0d5-4d41-8d09-db5fe32f0d68/instruct-dataflow-task-to-redirect-bad-input-rows-to-log-file?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case the root cause is a space before the comma on the quote qualified field.

Example: "John","Smith" ,"NY"  (There is a space after "Smith" and before comma)

Answer (score 0):

I was using $ as text delimiter in the dat file.
But, I changed the setting to none in the dat file.
This caused the error to resolve.