# Multi line Find and Replace get set property notepad++ or visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, notepad++, multiline, find-replace

I have to replace expression below:-

```
public string Body =>
        this._body;
```

To:

```
public string Body
      {
        get{return _body;} 
          set{_body = value;}
    }
```

I am using Notepad++ to find and replace as below:-
Find regx: `=>\s*.*?;`
Replace regx: `{get{return\s*.*?;} set{\s*.*? = value;}}`

which seems not working and replace it incorrectly without property name as below:-

```
Public string Body {get{returns*.*?;} set{s*.*? = value;}}
```

How can we change the expression to get the desired result with property name? 
Also can we do something like this in `Visual Studio`? Thank you.

Comment: Why use regx? Seems like you dont event need regx except maybe for whitespace. Visual studios find and replace always seemed to work great for me.

Comment: It seems to work for one. But we are trying to replace all such occurrence for all other properties too at once. We have several properties to be replaced. Looked into the visual studio multi line find and replace plugin but it is not able to find all regex.

Comment: Try what I posted. I copied and pasted into a file and scattered them all over the place and changed the whitespaces for some and it found them all using the Replace in Files using regx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job with Npp:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\b(public\s+string\s+Body)\s+=>\s+this\.(\w+);`
- Replace with: `$1 {get{returns $2;} set{$2 = value;}}`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This works for the find in VS2015 `(\bpublic\b[\s\r\n]*\bstring\b[\s\r\n]*\bBody\b([\s|\r\n]*)=>([\s\r\n]*)\bthis\b([\s\r\n]*)\b\._body\b)`

I would just use the find and click on the highlighted area and paste it in depending on how many replacements are happening. You would almost be better writing a small console app to iterate through all the files in a directory if they have the same file type .ext

I like this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1915666/1870110) where you could take it a step further and pass the directory and iterate through all the matching regx(*).cs files using [Directory.EnumerateFiles()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx)